# Get the name of an image selected Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, replace

I have this code to get rid of the fakepath:

```
var newValue = v.replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/g, '');
```

it´s working fine, the name of the image selected is shown like: image.jpg, but I want to get rid of the .jpg also and just get the name: image

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two lines like this:

```
var newValue = v.replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/g, '');
newValue = newValue.replace(/\.jpg$/, '');
```

You could do it in one line (but the problem is that this throws an exception if a match isn't made):

```
newValue = /^C:\\fakepath\\(.+)\.jpg$/.exec(v)[1];
```